# es6 javascript recommend way to apply template literal with ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator, template-literals

I am using eslint in my development with airbnb style guide. I am getting eslint error suggest using template literals instead of string concatenation (prefer-template).

It flags this line with error

`':<br><br><pre style="color:red">' + softTab + err.stack.replace(/\n/g, '<br>' + softTab) + '</pre>' : '';`

here is my code

```
const renderError = err => {
  const softTab = '&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;';
  const errTrace = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ?
    ':<br><br><pre style="color:red">' + softTab + err.stack.replace(/\n/g, '<br>' + softTab) + '</pre>' : '';
  return renderFullPage(`Server Error${errTrace}`, {});
};
```

My question is what is the recommend way to apply a template literal using ternary operator? I applied it on the function return but depending on where I apply the template literal on this line causes errors. Ideally I tried doing this whole line but I get a problem with with trying to pass `${softTab}` to the `err.stack.replace(/\n/g, '<br>' + softTab)`any suggestions or solutions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why you need `<br>` when you already have a `<pre>`?

Comment: good catch! not sure why, I guess for line breaks? remove the <br> entirely?

Comment: Yes indeed. I even would avoid the "softTab"s and just give the `<pre>` element a `padding-left: 4ex;` :-)

Answer (score 2):

In ES6 you can use template literals instead of string concatenation.  To do this you use back-tick (`)(grave-accent) character instead of double or single quotes.  The template literals can contain place holders.  These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (${expression}).  So your case:

```
`:<br><br><pre style="color:red">${ softTab }${ err.stack.replace(/\n/g, `<br>${softTab}`) }</pre>`
```

For further reading on this: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have a lot to do with the ternary operator. You should just replace the string concatentation with the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (or at least, that style guide says you should do that):

```
`:<br><br><pre style="color:red">${ softTab }${ err.stack.replace(/\n/g, `<br>${softTab}`) }</pre>'
```

---

That said, you might want not to use a ternary at all here:

```
function renderError(err) {
  const softTab = '&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;';
  let message = 'Server Error';
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    message += ':<br><br><pre style="color:red">';
    message += softTab + err.stack.replace(/\n/g, '<br>' + softTab);
    message += '</pre>';
  }
  return renderFullPage(message, {});
}
```

Or maybe, using CSS instead of `<br>` tags and "soft" tabs:

```
function renderError(err) {
  let message = 'Server Error';
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production')
    message += `:<pre style="margin-top:2em;padding-left:3em;color:red;">${err.stack}</pre>`;
  return renderFullPage(message, {});
}
```

Comment: this throws up errors about spacing...was able to apply `:<br><br><pre style="color:red">${softTab}${err.stack.replace(/\n/g, `<br>${softTab}`)}</pre>`

Comment: You mean the eslint config doesn't like the spaces that pad the substitution expressions? Well, choose the better one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with to suite airbrb style guide.

```
const renderError = err => {
  const softTab = '&#32;&#32;&#32;&#32;';
  const errTrace = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ?
    `:<br><br><pre style="color:red">${softTab}${err.stack.replace(/\n/g, `<br>${softTab}`)}</pre>` : '';
  return renderFullPage(`Server Error${errTrace}`, {});
};
```